# Adding Angular Material to Nx Workspace

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

I'm getting started with Nx and I'm following the tutorial available on their website https://nx.dev/angular
Now I'm trying to add angular material to my project. A simple `ng add @angular/material` would do the trick, but only for the root app. What I'm trying to achieve is having all of my apps and libraries to use the same Material Theme. So I want my root app to use it as well as my other components under libs, e.g. `HeaderComponent`. I couldn't find any tutoriol to clarify that till now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed your libs and apps with nx?

Once you install Angular Material with npm, you'll need to add manually Angular Material to every app and library module.

Let's say you have a library called "shared-ui", it probably has root module, add Angular Material in to imports, and exports if you'll want it to use across all library.

Comment: And what about the theme? How can I share the palette and mixins between all components and libraries?

Comment: Supose you have a MaterialModule with all the imports from Material you will use in a Nx workspace. Do you need to do the same import on each app and lib in the Nx workspace that uses angular material or can you use that one MaterialModules across libraries?